# Expression Language not executing in facelets template and client

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, facelets

How do I get the EL below to execute?  I'm using Glassfish and Netbeans.  I tried a few variations on the web.xml, but I'm not exactly sure that's the problem.  Perhaps it's the imports for the client or template?

output:

```
thufir@dur:~$ lynx http://localhost:8080/HelloExpressionLanguage/ -dump
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="top">
                top
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
                expression language not evaluating?
                <h:outputLabel value="#{hello.hi(fred)}" />
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>thufir@dur:~$
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <!--
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
        -->
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>client.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

client:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="top">
                top
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
                expression language not evaluating?
                <h:outputLabel value="#{hello.hi(fred)}" />
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

template:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
        <title>Facelets Template</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="top" class="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="content" class="center_content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
        </div>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

bean (using "gonna be deprecated" `@SessionScoped):

```
package pkg;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Hello {

    public Hello() {
    }

    public String hi(String name) {
        return "hi " + name;
    }

}
```

Comment: @BalusC ok, I was trying to ask a smaller scoped question.  I updated the linked question.

Comment: that was inadvertent; those other points were just for background.  Anyhow.